# Error in updating textfield while server is in infinite loop

Tags: java, serversocket

I have a TCP client that will send the data to my TCP Server. The ServerSocket in TCP server are always waiting for the incoming request from client in infinite loop of while(true). I want to always update my textfield based on the request from the client, my serversocket is in the while(true) where the data from client reside. How to achieve this?

//summary of my current code

```
Text txtOne;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  window.open();
}

void open()
{
  createContents();
}

createcontents()
{
  txtOne = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

Button btnStartServer = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnStartServer.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    toServerController();
    }
  });
}

void toServerCOntroller()
{
  try
   {
     ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(60000);
     while (true)
    {
      Socket sclient = server.accept();
      DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(sclient.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(sclient.getOutputStream());

     String name = dataIn.readUTF();
     txtOne.setText(name); //<----- this is where the error happen
   }
}
```

I expect the txtOne will always change based on the dataIn.

Comment: you gonna need another thread

Comment: fetch all the data in a second thread and keep the main one for the ui

Comment: `public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
   new Thread(()-> toServerController()).start();
    }`

Comment: and then hope the Text element is Thread safe

Comment: Your suggestion is working fine, its just that the text element is not thread safe as u mentioned before.

Comment: Sorry im not an expert in inter thread communication

Comment: But you can try the following : create class extending interruptedException where you can pass a string and throw it instead of setting the text then in the main thread you catch it set the text and either .notify() the thread (not sure if it stillexists at that point) or completely start a new one doing the same thing

Comment: aside from that you can have a look around the java.concurrent package ans dee if you find anything useful oO

Comment: Oh first try setting txtOne to synchronous (public/private ...) synchronous Text textOne